# How can sum values from the previous month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to sum amounts from the previous month typed (SET)

Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tester (
date_amount date,
amount int);


INSERT INTO tester VALUES
("2014-08-01", 1000),
("2014-08-02", 1001),
("2014-08-03", 1002),
("2014-08-31", 2000),
("2014-08-31", 2000),
("2014-08-31", 2000),
("2014-09-01", 1006);
```

Here in the example for example

If I type year= 2014 and month= 9, I should sum automatically the last day of the month typed in this case all amounts in "2014-08-31"

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b7e19/1):

```
SET @month := 09;
SET @year := 2014;

select sum(amount) from tester 
where   month(date_amount)= @month-1
```

The query must sum all amounts of the last day of previous month typed

I must have as result this:

```
SUM(AMOUNT)
6000
```

I tried this but is not the correct way because here I know the last day of the month:

```
SET @month := 09;
SET @year := 2014;

select sum(amount) from tester 
where   month(date_amount)= @month-1 and day(date_amount)= 31
```

I also tried this query but got NULL

```
SET @month := 09;
SET @year := 2014;

SELECT sum(amount)FROM tester 
WHERE month(date_amount)= @month-1 AND day(date_amount) =last_day(day(date_amount))
```

Please somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just providing month and year provide an actual date and then you can get the results you wanted

```
SET @month := 09;
SET @year := 2014;

SELECT sum(amount)FROM tester 
WHERE month(date_amount)= @month-1 AND day(date_amount) = day(last_day(date_amount))
```

alternatively, you could use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the month and year given to date first and use that instead of `@Date`

Comment: @ThanatosSama I just noticed you almost had the right answer. In your second attempt where you got `null` if you change the second condition of where clause to `day(last_day(date_amount))` that works too. reason you were getting null is because last_day returns a date which won't be equal to what `day` returns(integer).

Comment: Oh man sorry I didn't noticed that you wrote @ date i don't want to type the date just month and year.

Comment: @ThanatosSama As I explained in my comment, I've changed the answer to reflect those changes and now you won't need to enter date. It should be an acceptable answer now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM Tester
WHERE date_amount = LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(@Month + '/00/' + @Year, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

If you use a function on part of the row in the table, you force sql to do a table scan.  If you convert the data to a complete field, it can use indexes in the search.

Comment: You were near to the answer but i found that if the translation is ilegal will return NULL but thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

This may help :

```
SET @month := 09;
SET @year := 2014;

SELECT sum(amount) FROM tester 
WHERE month(date_amount)= @month-1 and date_amount = last_Day(date_amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated it's better to compare a column without first appling a function

```
SET @month = '09', @year = '2014';

SELECT
    SUM(amount) total
FROM
    tester
WHERE
    date_amount = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', @year, @month, '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the first and last day of the month use only the year and month with TO_CHAR(YYYYMM)

```
select sum(amount)
 from tester 
group  by to_char(date_amount, 'YYYYMM');
```

In Mysql you could use DATE_FORMAT(date_amount, '%Y%m') instead of to_char

Comment: The query must sum all amounts of the last day of previous month typed